# Webview to display pdf file in offline mode

Tags: android, android-webview, android-pdf-api

Using webview the following code will execute fine on online and it will display the PDF file. After that if i goes to offline it will not display the cached pdf file.

```
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String pdfStr="https://www.sample.structure.first.pdf";
mWebview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfStr);
```

But i need to cache the pdf and display it on offline mode also. Anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your work in cache of Web view using following:

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { 
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

webView.loadUrl( "your_url" );
```

Add this method to check if network is available:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Add these permissions in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Still it is not working.  It shows "Couldn't find the URL Click refresh to reload the page."